# Files in Public folder don't show up [Laravel]

Tags: php, laravel, .htaccess, public

I have a website in production that cannot access some folders in public/css. I checked permissions on all folders, checked my .htaccess in public folder, I cannot find the reason why some folders show up in my local version [Local](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Py5oc.png), but not in my production version [Prod](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hebni.png).

For example for this :

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('css/directives/gallery.css') }}"/>
```

In my local version, it works because the folder directives shows up, but in production I get a 404 error.

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

This is how it looks on my production server [Production Files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8NIXx.png), and inside [directives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfY83.png)

Website is written in PHP using Laravel 5.4, below is my .htaccess file in production, it is the same as in my local version.

Thanks

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>
    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: I can not found directives folder in css folder. Let recheck you directories in your production.

Comment: I do have the same directories in my production as in my local version

Comment: Because your load css file with url "css/directives/gallery.css", but this file is not exists in "directives" folder in your production, so it get error 404.

Comment: Here, take a look at the files in [Production](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CfY83.png) I do have gallery.css

Comment: Let post full URL of file "gallery.css" in your HTML.

Comment: I tried that too, it doesn't work either

Comment: Check if it is SSL issue.

Answer (score 0):

Give all permissions to the public folder
chmod -R 777 public

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/directives/gallery.css') }}"/>

Comment: <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('public/css/directives/gallery.css') }}"/>

Comment: Try this because your all css file is in public folder.

Comment: The problem is only permissions, so try to give 777 to the exact folder you are accessing and make sure that permissions are installed.

Comment: It doesn't work, I also did give 777 to all folders and files in public recursively, it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Is the owner and the group of 'directives' directory the same as in other directories ?

Comment: you could try <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "{{ url('/') }}/assets/css/directives/gallery.css"/> ,but I believe that you uploaded or created  'directives' directory not in the same way that you did with the other directories in production server